# How to export workflow summary view?

Tags: features, workflows

I customized the workflow summary view to make multiple views for different users/workflows.

When I try to export it with features, module.views_default.inc is not created, no error (nor notice) message is issued, and the workflow_summary view is deselected from the feature (re)creation form. I've created a feature with only this view, and then get an empty feature.

Is there a way to export it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that it's better to clone the view to export it as usual than edit default one.

There's also an "export" button on the view definition page that can be used to copy-paste definition manually.